# DFS path finding with obstacles

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I have the following grid and i'm trying to get to the 1's in that grid, the obstacle is shown by 2. The robot has prioritized movement in this order: up, right, down, left. The starting position has a * next to it.

```
 0   0*  0
 0   2   0
 1   1   0
```

What i have done so far is to put the position of that grid into a graph form, and also generated all the possible moves from each position in the prioritized order. But my issue is that the algorithm gets stuck in a loop when it gets to the last section of the second row. I'm trying to implement some sort of a cycle detector so i don't get stuck in that loop.

I should also mention that the robot can visit the same position twice as long as it's through different paths. So what I have so far is:

```
def dfs(grid,start):

    #find the routes in U,R,D,L order
    height = len(grid)

    width = len(grid[0])

    routes = {(i, j) : [] for j in range(width) for i in range(height)}

    for row, col in routes.keys():
      # Left moves
     if col > 0: 
          routes[(row, col)].append((row , col - 1))
      # Down moves    
     if row < height - 1:
          routes[(row, col)].append(((row + 1, col)))
     # Right moves
     if col < width - 1: 
         routes[(row, col)].append(((row , col + 1)))
     # Up moves
     if row > 0:
         routes[(row, col)].append(((row - 1, col)))

  #find the blocked ones

   blocked = {(i,j) for j in range(width) for i in range(height) if grid[i][j] == 2}

   path = []

   stack = [start]

   while stack:
     node = stack.pop()

     if node not in blocked:
         path.append(node)
         stack = []
         for x in routes[node]:
             stack.extend([x])

  return path
```

Where

```
 grid = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
 start = (0,1)
```

Doing this by hand shows that the path should go as follows: right, down, down, left, right, up, up, left, left, down, down

any suggestions on how i can implement the detector would be great, I'm very new to AI and python and i've been trying to figure this out all day...thank you

Comment: What makes the path terminate at `(2, 0)`? Should it terminate when all cells have been visited or all 1's have been visited or is there some other condition?

Comment: Does the robot **have** to take the preferred step before trying the other options? If maze is `1  0  0*` is the correct answer left, left or no path?

Comment: The path terminates when all 1s have been visited, and the robot takes the step in the preferred order so if the maze is 1 0 0* it would try up, right, down, but those aren't possible moves so then it goes left left

Comment: Has your problem been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def dfs2(grid,pos,curr,height,width):
    x = pos[0]
    y = pos[1]    
    if grid[x][y]==1:
        print str(curr)
        return None
    elif grid[x][y] ==2:
        return None        
    last = curr[-1]    
    if x-1 >= 0 and last != 'DOWN':        
        curr.append('UP')
        dfs2(grid,(x-1,y),curr,height,width)
        curr.pop()
    if y+1 < width and last != 'LEFT':        
        curr.append('RIGHT')
        dfs2(grid,(x,y+1),curr,height,width)
        curr.pop()
    if x+1 < height and last != 'UP':
        curr.append('DOWN')
        dfs2(grid,(x+1,y),curr,height,width)
        curr.pop()
    if y-1>=0 and last != 'RIGHT':
        curr.append('LEFT')
        dfs2(grid,(x,y-1),curr,height,width)
        curr.pop()


def dfs(grid,pos):
    dfs2(grid,pos,['START'],len(grid),len(grid[0]))

########MAIN#########
#up, right, down, left
grid = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
start = (0,1)
print str(grid)
dfs(grid,start)
```

This is based on recursion. Attemps to move to the next position based on the order specified in the question and stores the movements in a list which gets printed on reaching the destination

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how this is working, the code gives two solutions both starting at the start position, however, once it gets to the first solution it's supposed to continue on the same path, not start again at (0,1). I'm having trouble identifying the part that starts again at (0,1) a second time

Comment: Actually i managed to fix that part but this isn't right, because instead of backtracking once it gets to (2,1) it just goes left

Comment: `if grid[x][y]==1:
            print str(curr)
            return None`
So it should return once the solution is found.
Did you remove the return?

Comment: This is my output:
['START', 'RIGHT', 'DOWN', 'DOWN', 'LEFT']
['START', 'LEFT', 'DOWN', 'DOWN']

Comment: Right so your output should actually be ['START,'RIGHT', 'DOWN', 'DOWN', 'LEFT','RIGHT', 'UP', 'UP', 'LEFT', 'LEFT', 'DOWN', 'DOWN']

Comment: it's not supposed to start from (0,1) twice, it's supposed to continue going until it finds both 1's

Comment: `['START', 'RIGHT', 'DOWN', 'DOWN', 'LEFT','LEFT']` should be fine right?

Comment: no because the priority is UP RIGHT DOWN LEFT, so once it hits the first 1 then the path is different so it goes RIGHT', 'UP', 'UP', 'LEFT', 'LEFT', 'DOWN', 'DOWN'

Comment: Did you try commenting all the 4 `curr.pop()` in the code?

Comment: Eitherway I fixed that part but there are too many recursions and if i expand the grid to a 4x4 or 5x5 i get "maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp"